Getting BadDeviceToken Error for VoIP Push Notifications in Sandbox Environment Only
I’m experiencing a BadDeviceToken error when trying to send VoIP push notifications through the sandbox environment (https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com). This error appears even though everything works perfectly in the live environment (https://api.push.apple.com), where the same setup delivers notifications as expected.
Context of the Setup:

I’m using Xcode, and the entitlements file has aps-environment set to development.

VoIP push notifications work correctly in production, confirming that tokens are generated and used without any issue.

The issue is specifically isolated to the sandbox environment; I only encounter the BadDeviceToken error there.

I ensured that the app is installed via Xcode (and not through TestFlight), so it should use the sandbox environment correctly.

The device token used for sandbox is freshly generated within the app, specifically intended for sandbox testing.


Given this setup, I expected the VoIP push notifications to work in both environments, especially since they are functional in the live environment. However, I continue to get a BadDeviceToken error when testing in the sandbox environment.
Is there something specific to sandbox VoIP push notifications or VoIP token generation that could be causing this discrepancy? Any advice on further troubleshooting steps would be helpful!
